# Proper way to cite work done in Python, Basemap, Geos, and Proj4

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I've recently been making many types of maps and graphs using Python.

All of the maps were made inside of matplotlib with Basemap, which has the dependencies of GEOS and Proj4. I'm making these for a professor that I'm working for at my university.

I am not entirely sure of the proper way to give credit to the software that was used to generate these in case any of the graphics I've been making get put into a publication.

What is the appropriate way to cite software?

Comment: This might be better suited to [academia.se], but note that people generally avoid handing out legal advice on the internet - stick to *"appropriate ways to cite software"* rather than *"avoiding copyright infringement"*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about code-related issues in a programming sense. And I doubt that any other stack-site would provide legal advice.

Comment: While I understand that this is not about code, it is not a moot issue and very much applies to programmers in general, not just those in an academic setting. I will, of course post this in academia. However, I believe it would be prudent to leave it open here to any other people who might actually find this useful, or possible even have more information about this.